# Issue with CPT posts within WP REST API showing as []

Tags: custom-post-types, rest-api

When I am querying for posts of a CPT, I get a response of 200 but a return of brackets [].

How can I show all of my CPT post data?

My syntax I am using in the url is: `http://mydomain/wp-json/wp/v2/myCPT`

Comment: Did you set `'show_in_rest' => true,` when registering the post type?

Comment: Yes. It is. And if I add an ID to the syntax it will show just that 1 post. But I was trying to get a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried everything and every plugin to fix my issue and expose the list CPT data instead of showing brackets [ ].

And the answer is something that might be a bug in Wordpress Rest API.

The problem was I am using **custom statuses** and none of my posts were assigned as default Wordpress status. After changing the posts to any of the default built-in statuses, it worked. But doesn't work for custom statuses it seems.... at least not with custom statuses created with a plugin called PublishPress.. Perhaps it just doesn't work with custom statuses at all, all-around

Hope this can help someone else!

Comment: Most likely related to the fact that the default post status of `WP_Query` is `'publish'`.  Did you modify the rest query to solve this?

Comment: No, I've modified the actual post and change the status to any of the defaults (e.g: Published, draft, etc) and the posts all shows!... This is something that WP-API should look into and account for when dealing with custom statuses.